# I subclassed UIView. Some of its subviews are animated. What's the correct way to restart these?

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, subclass, restart

OK, so I subclassed UIView and the view has a bunch of subviews.  These subviews are animating.  When i push another View Controller on top, or the app goes into the background, the animations stop.

What is the correct way to restart these animations in my subview.  I don't want to have the View Controller tell the View to restart them, because I feel like the View should know when it needs to restart without being explicitly told by another object.

But I can't use layoutSubviews on the the subclassed UIView because the animations that are happening are adding new UIImageViews.  When that happens, layoutSubviews gets called on the UIView subclass.  So layoutSubviews is being called a lot and I can't use it to restart the animations.

Thoughts?

UPDATE - The animation code looks like this... but i don't think that really matters.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_DURATION delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear     animations:^{
    [subview setFrame:finalFrame];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}];
```

Comment: Can you post some code to illustrate your problem? Specifically, how are you doing the animation (a `+[UIView animate...]` call, maybe?), and what exactly does your `-layoutSubviews` do?

Comment: You can check if a view is visible by  view.superview != nil and start your animations.

Comment: The view always has a superview.  I want an elegant way to trigger the restart.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSNotificationCenter to notify the view that the view controller has come up again like so:

In your UIView, add this in the init method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(methodToExecuteWhenUIViewControllerComesBackUp:) name:@"Came Back" object:nil];
```

Then in your "Other viewController", in the method where you present your original controller again, add:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Came Back" object:nil];
```

Then when you present your original viewController back, your UIView will be notified. Repeat the first piece of code for each of the subviews that you want to reanimate.

When any subview gets removed(freed) for memory make sure to execute:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

If the above code is not executed, notification center will try to notify an object that no longer exists, causing your app to crash.

Comment: I could do something like this, but I really don't want to have to put this code in the view controller.  I feel like the view should be able to handle reseting itself as necessary.  Know what I mean?

Comment: I understand, but UIView's don't simply "know" when to reanimate... This code is relatively lightweight, I really dont see why you cant insert the code, tell me if it is a specific reason.

Comment: Yes, I'm probably going to resort to using something like this.  I was hoping there was an elegant way.  It doesn't feel elegant since I need to expose a method on the view to restart the animations and call this from 2 places in the view controller.  Then when i use this view in any other place, I need to do the same thing.  I can certainly do it, just seems like there is a better way.  layoutSubviews would almost work... except that part of the animation is adding new subviews, which triggers layoutSubviews.  so i can't.  oh well, maybe i just settle for now and move on.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `UIView Animation` , You had better use `Core Animation`

In `CAAnimation` it has a property called `removedOnCompletion` it default `YES` set it to `NO`(`yourCAAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;`) it will make your app from `background` to `foreground` , the animation also `animated`

Apple said:

**removedOnCompletion**

```
Determines if the animation is removed from the target layer’s animations upon completion.

@property(getter=isRemovedOnCompletion) BOOL removedOnCompletion
Discussion
When YES, the animation is removed from the target layer’s animations once its active duration has passed. Defaults to YES.

Availability
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Related Sample Code
MoveMe
Declared In
CAAnimation.h
```

Comment: It doesn't sound like removedOnCompletion will help me.  The animations are stopped when the view leaves the foreground, not when they complete.  Though they do it then too.  Doesn't seem like this will help me.